# MySQL: Perform type conversion in BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have two tables, `pattern` and `pattern_optimized`. Some of the fields in the `pattern` table are defined as `BIGINT(20) DEFAULT '-1'`, which is way too big for the data they hold; Additionally, `-1` is used as "not set" (zero is a valid value) - no other negative values are used otherwise.

The `pattern_optimized` table uses a new data format for these rows, defining them as `INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL`. I would now like to copy the data from `pattern` to the `pattern_optimized` table.

This would be easily done using `INSERT INTO pattern_optimized SELECT * FROM pattern`, but obviously all negative values are out of range now, resulting in warnings like this:

```
100 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 
1264 Out of range value for column 'version' at row 1 
1264 Out of range value for column 'triggered' at row 1
...
Records: 100  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 357
```

My first idea was to create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `negativeValueFix` BEFORE INSERT ON `pattern_optimized`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.version < 0 THEN 
        SET new.version = NULL; 
    END IF;
    -- ...
END
```

but unfortunately this doesn't help either: The same warning pops up and all values that used to be `-1` in the original table become `0` in the new table (instead of `NULL`, which is - apart from being implemented in the trigger - also the default for the row). 
It seems that MySQL converts the value even before the trigger.

I know that I can solve this problem using a temporary table but I'd rather not do that. The `pattern` table is unpleasantly large and I don't want to do a stored procedure just for that.

Is there any other way or am I missing some simple point?

**EDIT**: There are quite alot columns in the original table that suffer from the SIGNED problem, so I was hoping to somewhat automate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a case statement? Something like:

`INSERT INTO pattern_optimized 
SELECT 
CASE version
    WHEN -1 THEN null
    ELSE version
END CASE AS version
FROM pattern`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that! The reason I'd like to do `INSERT ... SELECT *` is that there are quite a lot of these "SIGNED" fields and I was hoping I could steer around a full insert definition.

Comment: I suppose you could set the default value for your new table fields to some value that's not in the range of incoming data, then run the insert. You'll get the warnings, and the -1 will have been transformed to this new default. Then you update the table to set those values to null, then change the default value on the new table column back to null. But that seems like more work than transforming the data in a temp table or with an inline conditional. Also, you have to be absolutely certain that the "temporary default" you use really isn't in the range of incoming data.

Comment: Went with the IF() version and a view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add small condition to the SELECT statement, e.g. -

```
INSERT INTO pattern_optimized(version)
  SELECT IF(version < 0, NULL, version) version FROM pattern
```

...add other fields.

Comment: Same as @Raj - a great point I didn't know, but I was hoping to get around doing that for every field. (During the change, there will be inserts on the old table that I want to clone to the new table using a trigger there)

Comment: I accepted Rajs answer since he answered first + basically the same and has less rep. Upvoted your answer too though. Thanks alot!